# new to Liferay , i am unable to navigate through Pages using renderURL

Tags: liferay

I am new to Liferay , i am unable to navigate through Pages using renderURL , please tell me where i am doing a mistake
I am struck here , i am not able to navigate to the Second Page during on click of an hyper link as shown below

This is my First Page , where i am showing the First Page ( view.jsp ) , But from view.jsp , i am unable to show view2.jsp

```
public class TestPortlet extends GenericPortlet {

public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest,
RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
renderResponse.setContentType("text/html");
PortletRequestDispatcher rd = getPortletConfig().getPortletContext()
.getRequestDispatcher("/html/test/view.jsp");

if (rd != null) {
rd.include(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}

}

}
```

**This is my view.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <b>Sai Test Portlet</b> portlet in View mode.

<portlet:renderURL var="clickRenderURL">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/test/view2.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%=clickRenderURL %>">Click here</a>
```

**This is my view2.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <b>View 2 </b> portlet in View mode.
```

There are no errros in console mode , and i am uisng Liferay 6.1 version .

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the same using
"liferay-portlet:renderURL" tag.

Instead of using "portlet:renderURL" tag.

Rest all looks fine to me.